# Transform output of Php

Tags: php

If you example I have this php:

```
$var  = $_POST['somefield'];
```

and suppose the value of 'somefield' is 2050, how do I make php output this as:

```
2,050
```

instead of

```
**2050** ?
```

Comment: maybe edit your question??

2,050 instead of 2,050 ? My gosh they are same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format)

Example:

```
// assuming US format
echo number_format($_POST['somefield']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant: "2,050 instead of 2050"

Now you want to format the no, so that thousands are seperated by commas. Please have a look at [This](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

And as for your code you can do this (but please read that link before)

```
$var = $_POST['somefield'];
$var = number_format($var);
```